# How to install kivy 1.9 in Windows

Tags: python, windows-8.1, kivy

I have searched Online and have tried all by myself to install Kivy on my pc.

Technical Info:

```
Windows8.1 64 bit
python3.4.3
kivy 1.9.0 x64
cython 0.20.0
```

I have installed cython but when I try to install kivy it gives the following error:

```
ons.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\Users\Munanga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build
-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl_instructions.obj
    gl_instructions.c
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(76) : error C2065: 'glGenFramebuffers' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(76) : warning C4047: '==' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection f
rom 'void *'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(82) : error C2065: 'glIsRenderbuffer' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(82) : error C2065: 'PFNGLISRENDERBUFFERPROC' : undeclared identifier

    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(82) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(83) : error C2065: 'glBindRenderbuffer' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(83) : error C2065: 'PFNGLBINDRENDERBUFFERPROC' : undeclared identifi
er
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(83) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(84) : error C2065: 'glDeleteRenderbuffers' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(84) : error C2065: 'PFNGLDELETERENDERBUFFERSPROC' : undeclared ident
ifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(84) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(85) : error C2065: 'glGenRenderbuffers' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(85) : error C2065: 'PFNGLGENRENDERBUFFERSPROC' : undeclared identifi
er
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(85) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(86) : error C2065: 'glRenderbufferStorage' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(86) : error C2065: 'PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEPROC' : undeclared ident
ifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(86) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(87) : error C2065: 'glGetRenderbufferParameteriv' : undeclared ident
ifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(87) : error C2065: 'PFNGLGETRENDERBUFFERPARAMETERIVPROC' : undeclare
d identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(87) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(88) : error C2065: 'glIsFramebuffer' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(88) : error C2065: 'PFNGLISFRAMEBUFFERPROC' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(88) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(89) : error C2065: 'glBindFramebuffer' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(89) : error C2065: 'PFNGLBINDFRAMEBUFFERPROC' : undeclared identifie
r
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(89) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(90) : error C2065: 'glDeleteFramebuffers' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(90) : error C2065: 'PFNGLDELETEFRAMEBUFFERSPROC' : undeclared identi
fier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(90) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(91) : error C2065: 'glGenFramebuffers' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(91) : error C2065: 'PFNGLGENFRAMEBUFFERSPROC' : undeclared identifie
r
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(91) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(92) : error C2065: 'glCheckFramebufferStatus' : undeclared identifie
r
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(92) : error C2065: 'PFNGLCHECKFRAMEBUFFERSTATUSPROC' : undeclared id
entifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(92) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(93) : error C2065: 'glFramebufferTexture1D' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(93) : error C2065: 'PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTURE1DPROC' : undeclared iden
tifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(93) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(94) : error C2065: 'glFramebufferTexture2D' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(94) : error C2065: 'PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTURE2DPROC' : undeclared iden
tifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(94) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(95) : error C2065: 'glFramebufferTexture3D' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(95) : error C2065: 'PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTURE3DPROC' : undeclared iden
tifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(95) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(96) : error C2065: 'glFramebufferRenderbuffer' : undeclared identifi
er
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(96) : error C2065: 'PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERRENDERBUFFERPROC' : undeclared i
dentifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(96) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(97) : error C2065: 'glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv' : undecla
red identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(97) : error C2065: 'PFNGLGETFRAMEBUFFERATTACHMENTPARAMETERIVPROC' :
undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(97) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(98) : error C2065: 'glGenerateMipmap' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(98) : error C2065: 'PFNGLGENERATEMIPMAPPROC' : undeclared identifier

    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(98) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wgl
GetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(101) : error C2065: 'glIsRenderbuffer' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(101) : error C2065: 'PFNGLISRENDERBUFFERPROC' : undeclared identifie
r
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(101) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(102) : error C2065: 'glBindRenderbuffer' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(102) : error C2065: 'PFNGLBINDRENDERBUFFERPROC' : undeclared identif
ier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(102) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(103) : error C2065: 'glDeleteRenderbuffers' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(103) : error C2065: 'PFNGLDELETERENDERBUFFERSPROC' : undeclared iden
tifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(103) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(104) : error C2065: 'glGenRenderbuffers' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(104) : error C2065: 'PFNGLGENRENDERBUFFERSPROC' : undeclared identif
ier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(104) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(105) : error C2065: 'glRenderbufferStorage' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(105) : error C2065: 'PFNGLRENDERBUFFERSTORAGEPROC' : undeclared iden
tifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(105) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(106) : error C2065: 'glGetRenderbufferParameteriv' : undeclared iden
tifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(106) : error C2065: 'PFNGLGETRENDERBUFFERPARAMETERIVPROC' : undeclar
ed identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(106) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(107) : error C2065: 'glIsFramebuffer' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(107) : error C2065: 'PFNGLISFRAMEBUFFERPROC' : undeclared identifier

    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(107) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(108) : error C2065: 'glBindFramebuffer' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(108) : error C2065: 'PFNGLBINDFRAMEBUFFERPROC' : undeclared identifi
er
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(108) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(109) : error C2065: 'glDeleteFramebuffers' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(109) : error C2065: 'PFNGLDELETEFRAMEBUFFERSPROC' : undeclared ident
ifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(109) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(110) : error C2065: 'glGenFramebuffers' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(110) : error C2065: 'PFNGLGENFRAMEBUFFERSPROC' : undeclared identifi
er
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(110) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(111) : error C2065: 'glCheckFramebufferStatus' : undeclared identifi
er
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(111) : error C2065: 'PFNGLCHECKFRAMEBUFFERSTATUSPROC' : undeclared i
dentifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(111) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(112) : error C2065: 'glFramebufferTexture1D' : undeclared identifier

    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(112) : error C2065: 'PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTURE1DPROC' : undeclared ide
ntifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(112) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(113) : error C2065: 'glFramebufferTexture2D' : undeclared identifier

    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(113) : error C2065: 'PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTURE2DPROC' : undeclared ide
ntifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(113) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(114) : error C2065: 'glFramebufferTexture3D' : undeclared identifier

    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(114) : error C2065: 'PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERTEXTURE3DPROC' : undeclared ide
ntifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(114) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(115) : error C2065: 'glFramebufferRenderbuffer' : undeclared identif
ier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(115) : error C2065: 'PFNGLFRAMEBUFFERRENDERBUFFERPROC' : undeclared
identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(115) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(116) : error C2065: 'glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv' : undecl
ared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(116) : error C2065: 'PFNGLGETFRAMEBUFFERATTACHMENTPARAMETERIVPROC' :
 undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(116) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'wg
lGetProcAddress'
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(117) : error C2065: 'glGenerateMipmap' : undeclared identifier
    c:\users\munanga\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\kivy\kivy\graphics\gl
_redirect.h(117) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilat
ion
     **error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\
BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2**

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Us
    ers\\Munanga\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\\kivy\\setup.py';exec(com
    pile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __f
    ile__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Munanga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-hpxn0x
    6a-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" fail
    ed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Munanga\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-yjxbp0qr\k
    ivy
```

Please how to get kivy installed in Windows.

Comment: Use the precompiled binary [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy).

Comment: Sorry me name is Munanga Munsaka. I tried Malik Brahimi to install the precompiled binary but still the same error

Comment: Yes I have pip. I tried to use the pip method after I tried the python setup.py install method. But both gave the same error above.

Comment: So which wheel did you download and how did you install?

Comment: This on -- Kivy-1.9.1.dev0_21042015_git3849c9f-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

Comment: Did you run `pip install  Kivy-1.9.1.dev0_21042015_git3849c9f-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: I did but it gives an error about

Comment: Yes but it gives an error as follows:        
C:\Users\Munanga\Desktop\Kivy>pip install Kivy-1.9.1.dev0_21042015_git3849c9f-cp
27-none-win32
Collecting Kivy-1.9.1.dev0-21042015-git3849c9f-cp27-none-win32
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Kivy-1.9.1.dev0-210420
15-git3849c9f-cp27-none-win32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Kivy-1.9.1.dev0-21042015-git3849c9f-cp27-none
-win32. I tried both x86 and x64 wheels

Comment: It appears this I can't due to reputation issues on this site but let me try and   do it in the main question.

Comment: I tried but I could not upload the image. Maybe via email?

Comment: https://join.me/296-562-677

Comment: Did you figure out that other program?

Comment: Sorry my internet connection was cut